# Построение модели

Tags: python, orm, django

С питоном и джангой только знакомлюсь, поэтому возможно, что вопрос откровенно глуп.  Хочу выстроить следующую модель взаимоотношений (саша любит машу, маша любит пашу, а паша...).

Но python, из-за особенностей интерпретатора, требует, чтобы каждый класс мог бы ссылаться только на последующий. Я в итоге использовал костыль с пустым классом в начале, но django не отрабатывал и создавал пустую таблицу в ответ на мой костыль. Решил пойти в обход организовав такую модель:

```
class Head_Link(models.Model):
    pass

class Department(models.Model):
    head = models.ForeignKey(Head_Link, blank=True, verbose_name=u'Глава департамента')

class Person(models.Model):
    head =  models.ForeignKey(Head_Link, blank = True,
    verbose_name=u'Руководитель')

class Head(models.Model):
    head = models.ForeignKey(Head_Link)
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name='+')
```

Но так знаний по django-вской ORM  мало, не пойму, как этим чудом пользоваться, как, к примеру, прикрутить это все к админке? Отсюда вопрос: это решение имеет на жизнь и если да, то как им пользоваться? А если подскажите, пожалуйста, другое.

Answer (score 3):

[Lazy and recursive relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/fields/#recursive-relationships)

> To create a recursive relationship -- an object that has a many-to-one relationship with itself -- use `models.ForeignKey('self')`.
>
> If you need to create a relationship
> on a model that has not yet been
> defined, you can use the name of the
> model, rather than the model object
> itself:
>
> ```
> class Car(models.Model):
>     manufacturer = models.ForeignKey('Manufacturer')
>     # ...
>
> class Manufacturer(models.Model):
>     # ...
> ```

Comment: Благодарю, сейчас попробую.

Comment: Появилась одна проблема: Reverse query name for field 'head' clashes with field 'Person.division'. Add a related_name argument t
o the definition for 'head' Что за конфликт, и что такое related_name? Я использовал related_name='+' проблема уходила, но понимание не пришло))

Comment: Советую все же сначала прочитать [документацию по моделям в django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/models/).

Comment: Спасибо за совет(на безрыбье и ...), но я и так ее читаю, просто когда я наталкиваюсь на проблему перечитывать гору литературы не очень эффективно - все таки еще не fluent, поэтому и задал вопрос здесь. И кстати я часто рыскаю по stackoverflow и там очевидно видеть английский язык, но здесь - это как-то странно... Ведь форум читают и люди у кого проблемы с английским.

Comment: > И кстати я часто рыскаю по stackoverflow и там очевидно видеть английский язык, но здесь - это как-то странно... 

Мне казался очевидным тот факт, что большая часть технической документации написана именно на английском языке и что цитаты на этом языке на форуме разработчиков просто неизбежны.

Хотя по сути я согласен, что на русском форуме приятнее читать сообщения на русском языке. Будь у меня больше времени/желания, а проблема не такая элементарная, я бы, вероятно, перевел эту цитату.

Comment: > просто когда я наталкиваюсь на проблему перечитывать гору литературы не очень эффективно

Django имеет превосходную документацию и, я думаю, прочитав ее до начала разработки БД, вы бы вовсе избежали подобных проблем. Кроме того, я бы не стал это писать, если бы банальный поиск по `Ctrl+F related_name` не выдавал бы исчерпывающий ответ на ваш вопрос.

Т.ч я действительно рекомендую прочитать всю эту "гору литературы", уверен - это будет намного эффективнее, чем потом переписывать пол проекта из-за плохой архетиктуры.